# There are no primary or candidate keys in the referenced table 'table1' that match the referencing column list in the foreign key

Tags: sql-server-2008

This is my table1

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Kbr_ShiftMaster]
(
    [ShiftId] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [ShiftCode] [nvarchar](50) NULL,
    [ShiftName] [nvarchar](100) NULL,
    [ShiftStartTime] [nvarchar](10) NULL,
    [ShiftStartBreak] [nvarchar](10) NULL,
    [ShiftEndBreak] [nvarchar](10) NULL,
    [ShiftEndTime] [nvarchar](10) NULL,
    [CreatedBy] [int] NOT NULL,
    [CreateDate] [datetime] NULL,
    [ModifiedBy] [datetime] NULL,
    [ModifyDate] [datetime] NULL,
    [Active] [nvarchar](50) NULL,
    [Remarks] [nvarchar](500) NULL
)
```

I am adding a primary key to this table.

```
ALTER TABLE Kbr_ShiftMaster 
 ADD PRIMARY KEY(ShiftId, ShiftCode);
```

I have now table 2 in which i am adding two foreign keys

```
CREATE TABLE ShiftAssginMaster
(
    SAMID INT IDENTITY(1,1),
    EmpId INT,
    ShiftCode NVARCHAR(50) NOT NULL,
    STARTDATE DATETIME NOT NULL,
    ENDDATE DATETIME NOT NULL,
    [CreatedBy] [int] NOT NULL,
    [CreateDate] [datetime] NULL,
    [ModifiedBy] [datetime] NULL,
    [ModifyDate] [datetime] NULL,

    FOREIGN  KEY(EmpId) REFERENCES kbr_Emp(EmpId),
    FOREIGN  KEY(ShiftCode) REFERENCES Kbr_ShiftMaster(ShiftCode)
);
```

On executing this query i am getting this error

> Msg 1776, Level 16, State 0, Line 2
>   There are no primary or candidate keys in the referenced table 'Kbr_ShiftMaster' that match the referencing column list in the foreign key 'FK__ShiftAssg__Shift__4FBCC72F'.
>
> Msg 1750, Level 16, State 0, Line 2
>   Could not create constraint. See previous errors.]

Answer (score 1):

Your primary key is {ShiftId, ShiftCode}.

Any foreign key reference to that table has to reference *both* those columns.

So you need to do one of three things.

- Add the column "ShiftId" to the table "ShiftAssginMaster".
- Add a table of valid shift codes, and create a foreign key reference to *that* instead of "Kbr_ShiftMaster".
- Give up.

There are actually a couple more ways to handle this, but I think they cause more problems than they solve.

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure you want `Kbr_ShiftMaster` to have a two-column primary key?  That would mean that it was the combination of `ShiftID` and `ShiftCode` that was unique, not either column alone.

If you want `ShiftID` to be unique and also want `ShiftCode` to be unique, one of them needs to be the primary key and the other needs to have a unique constraint.

If you want `ShiftAssginMaster` to reference `ShiftCode`, `ShiftCode` will need to be the primary key, as only primary keys can be referenced in foreign keys.

That raises the question of why you need `ShiftID` at all. Your `ShiftCode` is what's called a semantic key, meaning that the value has meaning and isn't arbitrarily assigned, but generally it's considered better practice not to have semantic keys as primary keys.

Here's one reason why.  If you ever need to change a `ShiftCode` once it's in use, and `ShiftCode` is the primary key, you'll have a lot of problems getting it corrected in all the other tables that have records that reference that record. Whereas, if the `ShiftCode` was just an attribute of the shift used for display and data entry and wasn't the primary key, it would be trivial to correct its value.

So if it were up to me I'd standardize on using `ShiftID` as your primary key and have `ShiftAssignMaster` reference that in its foreign key.